# Get the Value of Year from a DateTime Column in Azure U-SQL?

Tags: azure, datetime, nullable, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am using U-SQL script to get the Datetime column data from the Azure DataLake Analytics Table. I am having a date of joining datetime column in a employee table, I want display only the year of joining from that column. There may be a chance of getting null value from the table.

> joineddate.HasValue ? joineddate.Value.Year.ToString() : joineddate AS JoinedDate

The above statement shows a error,

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'
```

Please Suggest me a way to do this thing.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have used ToString to the datetime column and got the desired output.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(joineddate.ToString()) ? joineddate.ToString() : joineddate.Value.Year.ToString() AS JoinedDate
```

Thanks.